# C# generics, design idea, maybe

Tags: c#, list, generics

I'm quite new to C# and I'm investigating its possibilities.

Right now I'm a bit confused in a way I wanted to use generics ... List kind of generics. I want to create a basic list functionality in a single parent class, and just name what class type should my subclass contain.

Say, I create a class

```
class ItemList<T> : IList<T> {}
```

and implement IList interface. T is defined within ItemList as

```
public T this[int index] { get; set; }
```

Then, I want to have one or more subclass of ItemList. For example

```
class ProductList : ItemList<ProductItem> {}

class CategoryList : ItemList<CategoryItem> {}
```

Now, as I implemented IList interface in ItemList, I was expecting to be able to access methods like IndexOf, Add, Insert with identifier this or on an instance of ProductList for example

```
ProductItem product = new ProductItem();
ProductList products = new ProductList();
products.Add(product);
```

3rd line products.Add is error.

> ProductList' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and
>   no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type
>   ProductList could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?

Am I missing some syntax part or this concept is impossible? The idea(for now) is just simplification of later usage - If I have a ProductList class it is logical it will contain ProductItem, why should I use it like

```
ProductList<ProductItem> products = new ProductList<ProductItem>();
```

I hope you get my point.

Edit - Just to be clear on object hierarchy here...
class ItemList implements IList interface with method stubs 
class ProductList inherits ItemList class
Method stubs throw error, but its happening at a runtime.

Details on ItemList

```
class ItemList<T> : IList<T>
    {

        public T this[int index] { get; set; }
        private List<T> fList = new List<T>();

        int IList<T>.IndexOf(T item)
        {
            return fList.IndexOf(item);
        }

        void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
        {
            fList.Add(item);
        }

        void IList<T>.Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            fList.Insert(index, item);
        }
        void IList<T>.RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
....
}
```

Comment: At first glance it looks okay, so what do you mean an error - compilation/runtime?

Comment: Are you implementing `IList<T>` because you want to learn how to generic collections work, or is there another reason you're avoiding inheriting from `List<T>` directly for this functionality?

Comment: I wonder, is it NotImplementedException?

Comment: I'm sorry I assumed people keep this in their little finger, everything is basics to me right now. Its a compile time error. I will update question.

Comment: How does ItemList implement Add? Show us the code. I would guess you're using explicit implementation, which does not make Add visible without a typecast.

Comment: These are just wrappers of a List instance ... this was just a simple test case of possibilities, nothing special..

Comment: Its not a problem to paste the code, but its quite trivial. I'll get it in the question it doesn't format here well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that was obvious. You implemented interface [**explicitly**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
. You can either cast products to ICollection<ProductItem> before calling method on it

```
(products as ICollection<ProductItem>).Add(product);
```

or, better, you can implement Add method implicitly, like this:

```
public void Add(T item) {
    fList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't aware of explicit/implicit difference. I'll mark your answer as correct as it did "hit the nail on the head".

Answer (score 2):

Since you are implementing an interface, you need to implement those methods with your own code.

Alternatively, you can inherit from List instead of IList.

Comment: It seems it was done. After all, the error is not in the declaration of the class...

Comment: Slightly pedantic: I wouldn't say "inheriting" from an interface, so much as it is "implementing" the interface. Otherwise, this is spot on.

Comment: Well, ItemList is implementing interface IList, with method stubs for most of the methods, I altered only Add and IndexOf. ItemList is a class not an interface, so ProductList is inheriting a class... or is it not?

Comment: I was thinking about inheriting List, but as a second option. Implementing IList, if it gets possible this way, should give me some other flexibility at a later time.

Comment: @Sofija - Generally speaking inheriting from `List<T>` is all 99% of cases require (or one of its related collections). I'm not saying there aren't niche cases where it is useful to have the additional flexibility but it is easy enough to change it later if necessary.

Comment: @M.Babcock - Thank you for that practical answer - you can put it as an answer and I will accept it if there comes no solution to this interface way.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9286526/120955) hits the nail on the head. When interface methods are implemented *explicitly*, you don't see them on variables that are typed based on the class type. You have to cast them to the interface that contains that method instead.

You've probably noticed that it took quite a bit of work to implement all the methods on the `IList<T>` interface. Are you sure this is what you want to do? It would be much simpler to just extend the `List<T>` class. Or, even better, why not just expose the list as a separate property?

```
public class ItemList<T>
{
    private List<T> _itemList = new List<T>();
    public IList<T> Items {get {return _itemList;}}
    // add other features here.
}
```

Of course, this is assuming that you have some other features you want to add to `ItemList`. It may actually make more sense just to skip the `ItemList<T>` class entirely:

```
public class ProductList : List<ProductItem> {}
```

In short, the pattern you're trying to accomplish is generally best avoided. If you share your reasons for why you think it's necessary we could probably show you other ways to accomplish the same result with a lot less work.

Comment: I don't believe this pattern is necessary at all, I'm just testing to see possibilities like I said, Idea in using interface instead of extending class is more flexibility at a later time. You can keep same standard methods to manipulate collection but alter the implementation any way you like, IList is used with gridviews.. I don't think this is really important for this question... in the end I might not use this organization here, I might use it someplace else..